# How to uninstall newly installed dependencies for a RPM package?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, fedora

Is there an easy way to make a list of the dependencies a newly installed RPM package will install with `yum`?

Example: If you do `yum install ruby` then it will also install some rubygems.

But when I uninstall the `ruby` package I also want to get rid of the dependencies it installed.

So my first idea were to make a list of those new packages, and then do an `rpm -e` on those when I uninstall `ruby`.

**Question**

How to make such list in an automated way?

Or is there an easier way then to have to manage text files with rpm package names?

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/remove-unused-packages

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`yum` keeps its own history, so you can find out when a package was installed or updated using its history.

For instance, `yum history packages-info ruby` will give you all the transactions involving ruby, where the oldest one is usually the one where the package was installed.

```
Transaction ID : 102
Begin time     : Thu Apr  3 17:15:17 2014
Package        : ruby-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.x86_64
State          : Install
Size           : 64,734
Build host     : buildvm-17.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Build time     : Thu Nov 28 06:01:20 2013
Packager       : Fedora Project
Vendor         : Fedora Project
License        : (Ruby or BSD) and Public Domain
URL            : http://ruby-lang.org/
Source RPM     : ruby-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.src.rpm
Commit Time    : Mon Nov 25 07:00:00 2013
Committer      : V?t Ondruch <vondruch@redhat.com>
Reason         : user
Command Line   : install ruby rubygems
From repo      : updates
Installed by   : Michael Hampton <error>
```

This will give you the transaction ID, which you can then look up and find the dependencies which were installed, e.g. with `yum history info <ID>`.

```
Transaction ID : 102
Begin time     : Thu Apr  3 17:15:17 2014
Begin rpmdb    : 2336:55d492c6f5d091f328529861bdf95111264337f6
End time       :            17:15:20 2014 (3 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 2346:ccca040d610665c49a1ff6a11f787f8d5aa6790d
User           : Michael Hampton <error>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : install ruby rubygems
Transaction performed with:
    Updated       rpm-4.11.2-2.fc20.x86_64                @updates/20
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
    Updated       yum-3.4.3-137.fc20.noarch               ?
    Updated       yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-9.fc20.x86_64 @fedora/20
Packages Altered:
    Install     ruby-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.x86_64           @updates/20
    Dep-Install ruby-irb-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.noarch       @updates/20
    Dep-Install ruby-libs-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.x86_64      @updates/20
    Dep-Install rubygem-bigdecimal-1.2.0-16.fc20.x86_64 @updates/20
    Dep-Install rubygem-io-console-0.4.2-16.fc20.x86_64 @updates/20
    Dep-Install rubygem-json-1.7.7-101.fc20.x86_64      @fedora/20
    Dep-Install rubygem-psych-2.0.0-16.fc20.x86_64      @updates/20
    Dep-Install rubygem-rdoc-4.0.1-2.fc20.noarch        @fedora/20
    Install     rubygems-2.1.11-115.fc20.noarch         @updates/20
    Dep-Install rubypick-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch            @updates/20
```

If the package was just installed, and hasn't yet been updated, you can rollback the transaction with, e.g. `yum history undo 102`. This won't work if any of the packages has been updated since installation, though, as it matches name, version and release.

And if you really *just* installed the packages, you can skip everything else and run `yum history undo last` to rollback the most recent transaction.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove them with `yum autoremove`.

Comment: When I tried this, it proposed to remove a few unnecessary packages, along with a whole bunch that I _had_ explicitly installed and want. I would be very careful when using this.

Comment: `yum autoremove` will remove all packages which were required for no longer available packages. If you want to keep them during `yum autoremove`, set them to manually installed first.

Comment: "yum autoremove"  doesn't work in centos 6.6 "No such command: autoremove. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help"